# BeSimple SoapBundle - Annotations: Handling circular references in complex types

Tags: php, symfony, soap, doctrine

I'm using the BeSimple SoapBundle to create a SOAP server but i'm having troubles with the following piece of code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

/**
 * @Soap\Alias("Item")
 */
class Item
{

    /**
     * @Soap\ComplexType("AppBundle\Entity\Item[]")
     */
    protected $items;

    /**
     * @Soap\ComplexType("string")
     */
    protected $name;
```

What i need to get is a tree of complextype items but i'm getting a circular reference error when using the annotation **@Soap\ComplexType("AppBundle\Entity\Item[]")**.

Any idea of how can i deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround for this issue. I think that it shouldn't be necessary but is the best and only way i found.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

/**
 * @Soap\Alias("ComplexItem")
 */
class ComplexItem extends Item
{        
    /**
     * @Soap\ComplexType("AppBundle\Entity\Item")
     */
    protected $item;

    public function setItem($item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
    }
```

---

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

class Item
{

    /**
     * @Soap\ComplexType("string")
     */
    protected $name;
```

Controller usage example:

```
/**
 * @Soap\Method("getItem")
 * @Soap\Result(phpType = "AppBundle\Entity\ComplexItem")
 */
public function getItem()
{
    $item = new ComplexItem();
    $complexItem = new ComplexItem();
    $complexItem->setItem($item);

    return $complexItem;
}
```

Hope it helps someone. If you know a better way to solve this, please, let me know.